# Do string manipulations on catalogsearch result url's query

Tags: magento-1.8, php, catalogsearch, search, advanced-search

I am trying to include "Category" search in the Advanced search of my project. By going through some Stackoverflow questions, I realized that magento has built-in code for category search but they haven't used it.

I mean while searching if I add a param as `cat` then that will represent Category. So, for example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=37&q=shoe
```

In the above url, the `cat` param represents the id of Category. Hence, the search of string `shoe` will be specific to the provided category id.

(*ignore me if this is a known thing and a unnecessary explanation*)

Now, what I am trying to do is split the search text in to two halves based on a colon(`:`). such that the first part will be the "*Category Name*" and the second half will be the "*Product Name*" then I will append the `catalogsearch/result` url this new params.

For example, if the search string provided by user is `Mobile:Blackberry`, then I will extract the category Id from the provided category name and pass the query as follows:

```
?cat=37&q=Blackberry
```

I am not sure where exactly I should do this string manipulations.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!

This was actually meant to be handled at javascript but not php as I was thinking.

The query was being generated by the form. I was not aware of the behavior that the form will pass the inside field attributes i.e *value* and *name* as query to the submit action url.

So, for example, if I have a simple form as follows:

```
<form id="some-form" action="http://www.google.com">
     <input id="category-search" style="display:none;" type="text" name="cat" value="Mobile" />
     <input type="text" name="q" value="Blackberry"/>
</form>
```

The above form will create the following URL on submit action:

```
http://www.google.com/?cat=Mobile&q=Blackberry
```

*In default magento, only one input field is present in the search form*

So, what I did is added a keypress event which runs whenever the user presses colon (`:`) and then splitted the value in search text to *Category Name* and *Product Name*. Like this:

```
Mobile:Blackberry
=>   CategoryName = "Mobile";
     ProductName  = "Blackberry";
```

I am just sharing the logic here.. I hope it will be helpful for someone.

**Hint**: I kept the `#category-search` as a `select element`, instead of `input` element as I shown above, this will have all the category and sub-category names. Like this:

```
<select id="category-search" style="display: none;">
    <option data-id="37">Mobile</option>  <!-- category Id and category name -->
    <!-- Many options here -->
</select>
```

Comment: You should think about having a select box for the category maybe, for better useability

Comment: Yeah I did kept a select box for category :).. I even explained the same in hint.. I think I am not clear in explaining.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry, I think I didn't to the end :-(

Answer (score 3):

I would try with explode:

```
list($categoryName, $productName) = explode(':', Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q'));
```

And when you set this up in the predispatch event, you can just put your category back into `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`, just check the code, where it gets the `cat` from.

I didn't find any code which reads the `cat` param, but I think you have tried it? :-)

Comment: Hi, I want to do this explode just before the page is rendered. I mean by default if I search anything that will be added to param `q` but I want to even add it to `cat` param. please help. If I got this then I can handle string manipulations as you explained above easily. and also I am not sure whether I should do this in javascript(client-side) or php.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: Fabian, I solved it and added as answer below.. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You cant simple change the url used, as this would need a redirect (what i dont suggest here)

But you can go into the controller_action_predispatch event and manipulate the request object.

for the event: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
there should be an event, which is only triggered for the catalogsearch.

for the request object: http://phprelated.myworks.ro/set-or-get-request-variables-in-magento/
but reading a bit into the search sure is better